# Best way to create a hashmap of arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, arraylist, hashmap

I have one million rows of data in .txt format. the format is very simple. For each row:

```
user1,value1
user2,value2
user3,value3
user1,value4
...
```

You know what I mean. For each user, it could appear many times, or appear only once (you never know). I need to find out all the values for each user. Because user may appear randomly, I used Hashmap to do it. That is: HashMap(key: String, value: ArrayList). But to add data to the arrayList, I have to constantly use HashMap get(key) to get the arrayList, add value to it, then put it back to HashMap. I feel it is not that very efficient. Anybody knows a better way to do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You don't need to re-add the ArrayList back to your Map. If the ArrayList already exists then just add your value to it.

An improved implementation might look like:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
```

while processing each line:

```
String user = user field from line
String value = value field from line

Collection<String> values = map.get(user);
if (values==null) {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(user, values)
}
values.add(value);
```

**Follow-up April 2014** - I wrote the original answer back in 2009 when my knowledge of Google Guava was limited. In light of all that Google Guava does, I now recommend using its `Multimap` instead of reinvent it.

```
Multimap<String, String> values = HashMultimap.create();
values.put("user1", "value1");
values.put("user2", "value2");
values.put("user3", "value3");
values.put("user1", "value4");

System.out.println(values.get("user1"));
System.out.println(values.get("user2"));
System.out.println(values.get("user3"));
```

Outputs:

```
[value4, value1]
[value2]
[value3]
```

Comment: Other answers are all correct. I just do not want to use outside libraries.

Answer (score 13):

Use Multimap from Google Collections. It allows multiple values for the same key

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 8 you can use `map.computeIfAbsent`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

```
Collection<String> values = map.computeIfAbsent(user, k -> new ArrayList<>());
values.add(value);
```

Comment: nice! exactly what I was looking for without adding a library.

Answer (score 4):

The ArrayList values in your HashMap are references. You don't need to "put it back to HashMap". You're operating on the object that already exists as a value in the HashMap.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to import a library.

```
package util;    

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.List;    

/**    
 * A simple implementation of a MultiMap. This implementation allows duplicate elements in the the    
 * values. (I know classes like this are out there but the ones available to me didn't work).    
 */    
public class MultiMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<V>> {    

  /**    
   * Looks for a list that is mapped to the given key. If there is not one then a new one is created    
   * mapped and has the value added to it.    
   *     
   * @param key    
   * @param value    
   * @return true if the list has already been created, false if a new list is created.    
   */    
  public boolean putOne(K key, V value) {    
    if (this.containsKey(key)) {    
      this.get(key).add(value);    
      return true;    
    } else {    
      List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();    
      values.add(value);    
      this.put(key, values);    
      return false;    
    }    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is the Multimap. You can get it from apache's commons collection, or google-collections.

http://commons.apache.org/collections/

http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/

> "collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K,
>   V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values."

Answer (score 0):

I Could not find any easy way. MultiMap is not always an option available. So I wrote something this.

```
public class Context<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    public V addMulti(K paramK, V paramV) {
        V value = get(paramK);
        if (value == null) {
            List<V> list = new ArrayList<V>();
            list.add(paramV);
            put(paramK, paramV);
        } else if (value instanceof List<?>) {
            ((List<V>)value).add(paramV);
        } else {
            List<V> list = new ArrayList<V>();
            list.add(value);
            list.add(paramV);
            put(paramK, (V) list);
        }
        return paramV;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it would be faster if you used a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList, as the ArrayList will need to resize when it nears capacity.

you will also want to appropriately estimate the capacity of the wrapping collection (HashMap or Multimap) you are creating to avoid repetitive rehashing.

Comment: ArrayList will almost certainly have better average performance, even with the resizing. LinkedList is a nice choice when you want all your operations to take roughly the same time, e.g., they are involved in UI and you don't want random delays when your user performs an action.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, `MultiMap` is your best option.

Depending on your business requirements or constraints on the data file, you may want to consider doing a one-off sorting of it, to make it more optimised for loading.

Comment: This should be a comment