# Dictionary class

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, multimap

Is it possible to have multiple values, for a single key, in the Java dictionary class?

Comment: See my answer below regarding Dictionary - it is considered an obsolete class.

Comment: What Java Dictionary class? Do you mean Hashtable?

Comment: This looks like a replay of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049833/multi-valued-hashtable-in-java, posted some 12 hours earlier. Both were asked by someone named Raji, but using different unregistered accounts.

Comment: @oxbow, http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html. I didn't know about this either, but Dictionary is an abstract superclass of Hashtable - and it's obsolete as Uri said. This question is quite clearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

First, regarding the dictionary class: That class is considered obselete, the documentation recommends using Map instead.

This kind of collection you are seeking is called a multimap.
You could implement one yourself with a list, but that is tedious.

You may want to use a MultiMap from either Apache Collections or from the Google Collections. While I am personally a fan of the apache collections, they do not really support generics, so a Google multimap may be safer.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Use a list as the value.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the MultiMap class from the apache commons collections

- http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular `Map` and have the values be `Collection`s:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

map.put(0, Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
map.put(1, new ArrayList<String>());

map.get(1).add("blag");
```

Or you can use [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

> A `MultiMap` is a `Map` with slightly different semantics. Putting a value into the map will add the value to a `Collection` at that key. Getting a value will return a `Collection`, holding all the values put to that key.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
> mhm.put(key, "A");
> mhm.put(key, "B");
> mhm.put(key, "C");
> Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
> ```
>
> `coll` will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".

(Unfortunately, `MultiMap` does not use generics.)

Comment: you can't use the type "int" as a generic parameter, because it's a primitive type. use Integer instead.

Comment: Google Collections would be much preferable to Apache Commons Collections. It's implemented with generics and other Java 5 features, and overall seems to be a better extension for Java Collections framework. See http://www.javalobby.org/articles/google-collections/ (search for "Apache Commons")

Comment: True, If there is no constraint such as a Java 1.4 compatible solution IMHO.