# HashMultiMap: different kinds of values, and example code?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, guava

I'm trying to create a HashMap mapping together three different values of two different types: a String key, and a String and integer pair of values. (I want to be able to sort the resulting collection by the integer values.) I found the HashMultiMap collection in Google's Guava project, which, if I understand it correctly, seems like it could do what I want. However, I'm having trouble understanding the documentation: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

It's much easier for me to see some sample code. I found the code at [Multi-valued hashtable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049833/multi-valued-hashtable-in-java) but it seems to assume that your values would be of the same type. Is it possible to create a HashMultimap with values of two different types? If so, could you give me some sample code to show me how? If not, what do you recommend I use instead?

Comment: You don't need that for your particular case... See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String,Pair<String,Integer>> = new HashMap<String,Pair<Integer,String>>();
```

`Pair` is a class that will hold your two values. It's pretty easy to write so I'm not gonna do that here.

Comment: Even better would be to use a specific class instead of `Pair<String,  Integer>`.

Comment: Yes agreed, But I thought it will go without saying and since OP wanted something like a pair of values that's what I posted...

Comment: OK, thanks. Pair or a wrapper class just seemed like very inelegant solutions, so I thought that a class like HashMultimap would be more appropriate. Guess not.

Comment: Key, Value is Key, Value.. Personally I don't think that approach is inelegant at all...