# how to add objects of class to hashMap based on their values?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I am retrieving number of values from database, that need to be added to a list and then to a MAP with specific Key based on their values, for example,

```
row 1   name = "A" category = "1"
row 2   name = "B" category = "2"
row 3   name = "C" category = "1"
row 4   name = "D" category = "3"
```

I need to put row1 and row 3 in a list and each of row2 and row 4 in a separate list, then 
put these three lists into MAP and use the category names (1,2,3) as keys of MAP.

```
MAP
   1 LIST1 (values of 2 rows)
   2 LIST2 (values of 1 row)
   3 LIST3 (values of 1 row)
```

I am not sure how to add them to the list and MAP.
My constraint is that not everytime that I retrieve the values the same rows will be retrieved, so everytime I may need different number of lists to keep the values of each category that has been retrieved.

My code is as following,

```
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SelectRows);
 Map map = new HashMap();
 if(rs.next())
 {
    item.setRowID(rs.getString("ID"));
    item.setName(rs.getString("Name"));                       
    item.setValue(rs.getString("Value"));
    item.setCat(rs.getString("Cat"));
    if(!map.containsKey(rs.getString("Cat"))){
        map.put(rs.getString("CatID"), new ArrayList());
    }
    map.get(rs.getString("CatID")).add(row);
 }
```

the last line runs into this error > "" the method add(Rows) is undefined for the type Object.
even if I add the object to a list I run into the same error, the method add(List) is undefined for the type Object.

Comment: @HussainAl-Mutawa, I tried to add them to MAP but because everytime I am getting different cateogotries not sure how to create lists and set the key of MAP.

Comment: I meant, can you show your code. It might be something wrong you did in trying to solve the problem.

Comment: see my updated answer, you need to cast the item you get from the map, or define the generic type ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a map of lists. As you read the records, if there exist a key (here is category) then add the current row to the list

```
 Map map = new HashMap()
 for( Row row : resultset ) {
      if(!map.containsKey(row.category)){
            map.put(row.category, new ArrayList());
      }
      map.get(row.category).add(row.name);
  }
```

**UPDATE**

the problem is that you need to specify generic type here

```
 Map<String, List<Rows>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Rows>>()
 while( rs.next() ) {
      Rows row = new Rows();
      /*
       * code to initialize the values of row from the record
       */
      String category = rs.getString("Cat");
      if(!map.containsKey(category)){
            map.put(category, new ArrayList<Rows>());
      }
      map.get(category).add(row);
  }
```

Comment: Actually I am creating an object for each row as they have many columns, and tried to add these objects to the code but it runs into error at the last line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map with category as the key and an ArrayList of lists as the value. ArrayList automatically changes size as you add to it. [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) uses put(key, value) to add elements.  [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) uses add(element) or add(index, element).

Comment: I have the same plan but as I said as may retrieve different rows with different categories each time how I can name the lists and set the key of map?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010879/best-way-to-create-a-hashmap-of-arraylist. If you need to add to a list in the map, simply get the ArrayList using category and add your new list to the end, delete a list, or do whatever you need to. Also, a Multimap from Google Collections (http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) lets you add more than one value for the same key.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use Map inside Map

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer,String>>();
```

Outer Map will category against map of rows and value. So that every time you want to look up value based on row you can do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use an array list and link list and vector space.

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<class-name(means object)>> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<Integer, Vector<class-name(means object)>> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<Integer, LinkList<class-name(means object)>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

So use one the them.

Answer (score 0):

I declared a variable with data type Map, as the following:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
```

After that, I can add an object as the following:

```
params.put("id", indicatorId);
```