# how to sort items of a MAP and remove one?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hashmap

I am using the following code to keep list of objects in a MAP,

```
 Map<String, List<Rows>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Rows>>()
 while( rs.next() ) {
      Rows row = new Rows();
      /*
       * code to initialize the values of row from the record
      */
     String category = rs.getString("Cat");
     if(!map.containsKey(category)){
         map.put(category, new ArrayList<Rows>());
     }
     map.get(category).add(row);
  }
```

is it possible to sort the values for each category? 
how to remove an item in a specific category?

Comment: Do you want to sort the values _ArrayList<Rows>_ for each category, right?

Comment: That is why in your last post I had asked you to use Map of Map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650122/how-to-add-objects-of-class-to-hashmap-based-on-their-values/12650204#12650204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove item use `remove()` method of map:

`map.remove(category)`

As far as I understand items of each category are stored in list, so sorting is simple:

`Collections.sort(map.get(category))`

You can customize your sorting using your custom `Comparator`.

EDIT:

If however you wish to sort *keys* into your map you have to use `SortedMap`, e.g. `TreeMap` and probably provide your comparator that knows to compare your categories. Otherwise keys will be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

@Eme If you want a map that is sorted by its key, it is called [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Besides if you want to remove one of the item from the List for a particular category, you can do the following:

```
List<Row> list = map.get(category);
list.remove(index of element you want to remove);
map.put(category, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to sort values in the category:
Use [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) instead of list to keep values sorted as they are added.

To remove you can use  map.get(category).remove(row); Or create a new class that inherits from map and overrides remove(..). You can put code here to remove from the list attached to a specific key rather than the map itself.

Answer (score 0):

use list to store items in ur categories. thers an API function to sort list. and use (map.remove(category) ).get(0) to get first item in ur category list