# Data Structure Set, List, Map or Tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, tree, set

I am trying to choose a Java data structure with the following properties

Key: Long

Value: Set

Is there a structure that I can index into and add values to the Set?

For example say I have the object <1, [a,b,c]> and I want to add d this so that the output is <1, [a,b,c,d]>?

Can this be easily done in java?

Comment: Consider a map, it's a simple Key Value pair.

Comment: What's wrong with a `Map<Long, Set<String>>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1011072/24396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the object `<1, [a,b,c]>` and I want to add d this so that the output is `<1, [a,b,c,d]>`?

```
Map<Long, Set<Character>
```

would work good

Comment: So map.put(long, val) will add to the values and not overwrite them?

Comment: you get the set first and then add

Comment: `map.get(1L).add('d')`

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use a third party library, **Guava** has Multimaps, which make it easy to store multiple values for a single key.

For example:

```
    import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;

    HashMultimap<Long, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
    multimap.put(1L, "a");
    multimap.put(1L, "b");
    multimap.put(1L, "c");
    multimap.put(1L, "d");
```

See [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you will be best served by a `Map<Long, Set<String>>`. In your example:

```
Map<Long, Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Long, Set<String>>(); 
Set<String> initialSet = new HashSet<String>();
initialSet.add("a");
initialSet.add("b");
initialSet.add("c");
myMap.put(1, initialSet);
myMap.get(1).add("d"); // to add the "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes a Map would work.

```
Map yourmap = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

`HashMap<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>();`

If you want to add something to it just

```
ArrayList<String> list = map.get(KEY_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK);
if(list == null){
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD);
    map.put(KEY_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK,list);
}else{
    list.add(STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD);
}
```

**Of course you can replace `ArrayList` with `HashSet` also with `Vector` and `TreeSet`**