# Dynamically Created ArrayList From User Input Without MultiMap

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to take user inputs and sort data into multiple ArrayLists inside a HashMap without the use of MultiMap.
I currently have this declaration:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

An example of what the user input looks something like this:

```
1 String
2 String
2 String_b
3 String
```

What I need the generated map to look like:

```
[1]
  ---- String
[2]
  ---- String
  ---- String_b
[3]
  ---- String
```

I've been looking around and I saw something Guava created involving MultiMap. The perfect senario is to be able to do something like `myMap.put(1, "String"); myMap.put(1, "String_b");` so I can add each element separately, rather than have to create the ArrayList first.

If I need to clarify, please let me know!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1010879/1646783

Comment: ah, yep. thanks. trying to see if this can be done without MultiMap. I'll make that more apparent in the body/title.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Guava's [`MultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) can do:

```
Multimap<Integer, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

myMultimap.put(1, "a");
myMultimap.put(1, "b");
myMultimap.put(1, "c");
myMultimap.put(2, "x");
```

Another option is [`MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from Apache Commons Collections.

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
mhm.put(key, "A");
mhm.put(key, "B");
mhm.put(key, "C");
Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

Comment: Is there a method of doing this without using MutliMap?