# How to Achieve Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I am Having data  in .txt file like this

```
ClassName | StudentName
----------|----------------
A         | Vinod
B         | Aditya
A         | Deepak
C         | Pavan
B         | Anand
A         | Arihant
C         | Dharmendra
A         | Poem    
C         | ganesh
B         | Paritosh
B         | Paritosh
```

I need to get the result like 
classname a and list of students in the class A
classname b and list of students in the class B
similarly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create a hashmap of arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010879/best-way-to-create-a-hashmap-of-arraylist)

Comment: Read a line from file -> get key -> get list by key ->  add to list new value.

Comment: Split your problem into steps... then tell us where you are stuck. We are not going to do your homework just with the "requirements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line and store it in a `List<String>`. Now suppose that all the lines a will be in that format:

> class studentName

You can use a `Collector` to acomplish your task.

```
 Map<String, List<String>> collect = list.stream()
            .map(string -> string.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0],
                    Collectors.mapping(o -> o[1],
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: i need it in 1.7version

Comment: @SchiduLuca btw, once code is edited, we usually delete the comments ;)